# Create new notebook at fixed size

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, customization

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> we are effectively doing `FrontEndTokenExecute["New"]` and, at least on Windows, a new window has a `WindowSize` equal to the current `Input/Selected Notebook's` `WindowSize`.

Can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> produce a notebook with fixed/predefined size? Is there any option for that?

---

[**This method**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2366/5478) works for things like `CreateDocument` etc. but not for my case.

There is also something like `CurrentValue["DefaultWindowSize"]` but it doesn't seem to affect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>.

Comment: This would be great - I hate it when the new window opens in full screen mode because I had the window I was in maximized.  And I'm the type to open 20 windows in the course of perfecting a new function.

Comment: @JasonB Exactly ;)

Comment: When I used Windows, I would take advantage of the 'Tile windows tall' menu option, but I don't think it is available for Linux

Comment: @JasonB That sounds similar to using `FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEndToken[FrontEndTokenExecute["New"], "TileWindowsTall"]]`.

Comment: @Karsten7 - thanks for that, it doesn't work perfectly for sure, but at least it puts all the available windows in a reasonable space.  Though if you have two monitors, both widescreen, then the resulting windows are far from ideal

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want to modify `MenuSetup.tr` you can evaluate:

```
SetOptions[
 $FrontEnd,
 NotebookEventActions :> {
   {"MenuCommand", "New"} :> CreateNotebook["Default"]
   }
 ]
```

which will add this to user's FrontEnd/init.m

["MenuCommand" example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66239/5478)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92006/discussion-on-answer-by-kuba-create-new-notebook-at-fixed-size).

Answer (score 10):

If one feels comfortable modifying **MenuSetup.tr**, replacing its seventh line with

```
            MenuItem["&Notebook (.nb)", KernelExecute[CreateNotebook["Default"]], MenuEvaluator->"System", Method -> "Queued", MenuKey["n", Modifiers->{"Control"}]],
```

will result in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> creating a new notebook with a window size of `CurrentValue["DefaultWindowSize"]`.

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateNotebook.html) "`CreateNotebook` allows any notebook option to be given." Therefore, if one prefers another `WindowSize`, one can for example use `CreateNotebook["Default", WindowSize -> Small]`.

Comment: It took me a while to find that file, on Linux it is at `$InstallationDirectory <>"/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/MenuSetup.tr"`