# How to set up the new Notebook frontend aligned to screen's TopLeft automatically?

Tags: front-end, customization

How to config the preference so that when a new Notebook frontend be created or opened then the Notebook be moved and aligned to screen's TopLeft with the screen's Height automatically?

On `Windows OS` platform there is `WindowsKey + LeftArrow` key-pressing combination to make it one another manually.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,WindowMargins] = {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic,0}};
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,WindowSize] = {Automatic, Scaled[1]};

nb = CreateDocument[];
```

do what you want? The above settings are only active during the current Mathematica session. If you want to make it permanent, use `$FrontEnd` instead.

Comment: It does not work with `Ctrl+N`. The solution in [100414](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100414/5478) does not work with CreateDocument though. What do you think about moving this answer there and marking this topic as a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks but the script runs in  `$FrontEndSession` case  `WindowsMargins` should be assigned with `{{-10,Automatic},{Automatic,0}}`, I don't understand why the value be negtive .  When `$FrontEnd` is applied, It doesnot work on UI operations.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Carl Woll's scripts, the following scripts work.

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd,WindowMargins] = {{-10, Automatic}, {Automatic,0}};(*{{0,Automatic},{Automatic,0}}*)
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd,WindowSize] = {Scaled[0.5], Scaled[1.01]};(*{Automatic,Scaled[1]}*)

SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 NotebookEventActions :> {{"MenuCommand", "New"} :> 
    CreateDocument[]}]
```

The `MenuCommand` is defined in `MenuSetup.tr` file located in installtion directory.
However, I'm not sure about one of the `WindowsMargins` value-elments be negative. The `FrontEnd` might get screen values in chaos in multi-monitors case.