# Change magnification only for NEW notebooks?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, customization

I'm using Mathematica 11.3. In an earlier version, there was, I believe, an option allowing one to change the magnification for new notebooks (created, say, using the menu item File > New or the corresponding keyboard shortcut).

Is there some option to still do this?

I do ***NOT*** want to just change the Global Preferences option Notebook Options > Display Options > Magnification, because that applies to *all* notebooks, including existing palettes.

Comment: You can use this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100414/5478 with e.g. `CreateNotebook["Default", Magnification -> 3]`. This will work for menu and Ctrl+N but not for CreateDocument and related functions, don't know if you want that too.

Comment: @Kuba: I added `SetOptions[$FrontEnd,NotebookEventActions:>{{"MenuCommand","New"}:>CreateNotebook["Default",Magnification->1.25]}]` to my `~/Library/Mathematica/Autoload/init.m`, but it has no effect.

Comment: Don't modify init.m, just evaluate it. I rephrased linked answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @Kuba: Yes, I understand that - but is there a way to "automate" this, so that I don't have to evaluate that `SetOptions` command manually each time I start Mathematica? (I did try in `init.m` wrapping the entire `SetOptions` expression with a `FrontEndExecute`, but that seemed to make no difference.

Comment: And it didn't work even if I start Mathematica with clear caches (although it DID add `NotebookEventActions:>{{"MenuCommand", "New"} :> 
  CreateNotebook["Default", Magnification -> 1.25]}` to my FrontEnd > init.m`.

Comment: You don't have to repeat it nor to touch init.m at all. If you evaluate `SetOptions...` in the notebook it will be preserved across FrontEnd sessions because we are setting options for a `$FrontEnd` which automatically saves it in `init.m`.

Comment: This is not working at all for me in Mathematica 11.3 under macOS Mojave. I also tried clearing caches before restarting Mathematica, but that did not do it, either. Which particular `init.m` should have that option as a result of evaluating the expression (once)?

Comment: I do see that the change has been made to my `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/11.3_init.m`, but *it has no effect* when I open a new notebook! (I'm using the Versioned Preferences option for Mathematica, so y `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/11.3_init.m` just contains `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"->True]`.

Comment: @Kuba: `SetOptions[$FrontEnd,NotebookEventActions:>{{"MenuCommand","New"}:>CreateNotebook["Default",Magnification->1.25]}]` is working at the current session but is not remembered, either in 11.3 or 12,0 Prerelease (macOS). This is even though `NotebookEventActions:>{{"MenuCommand", "New"} :> 
  CreateNotebook["Default", Magnification -> 1.25]}' now  appears in the `FrontEnd` > `12.0_init.m' and after I restart with rebuilt caches.

Comment: I also tried `SetOptions[$FrontEnd,NotebookEventActions:>{{"MenuCommand","New","Notebook"}:>CreateNotebook["Default",Magnification->1.25]}]`, but again it does nothing.