# Automatically load init.m without sharing CellContext

Tags: notebooks, packages, system

I'm trying to set up Mathematica such that all functions/variables defined in my init.m are automatically loaded into any new notebook I open. This works as a default, but I would also ideally like to set my `CellContext` to Notebook, such that notebook-specific functions/variables are not shared. However, doing this also makes init.m functions not work across new notebooks. I've tried figuring out how to do this with packages, but I haven't been able to find a clear resource on how I would set this up for my purposes.

To be succinct, what is the best way to set up a central file like init.m that is automatically loaded with each new notebook, but such that notebooks have their own context? Thanks for any advice/guidance you can give.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Create new notebook at fixed size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100432/5478) you can do:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, NotebookEventActions :> {
   {"MenuCommand", "New"} :> (
     CreateDocument[{}
     , CellContext -> Notebook
     , NotebookDynamicExpression :> Refresh[
         Get @ "init.m"
       ; SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookDynamicExpression :> Null]
       , None
       ]
     ]
   )
}]
```

But do not define your functions in init.m, put there only `` Needs @ "MyPackage`" `` and create a proper packages. That way you don't need to read a long file each time you open a notebook but all will be done by fetching a `` "MyPackage`" `` from `$Packages` to a local to your notebook `$ContextPath`.

Comment: Big +1 for "But do not define your functions in init.m". Putting too many things in `init.m` is dangerous. You will forget about what you put there and eventually it may cause subtle, hard to debug problems.

Comment: Basically the only thing I put in `init.m` is setting the `$Path` so that my packages get picked up.

Comment: @Szabolcs I only have ``Needs@"GeneralUtilities`"`` there, and I try to install my utilities packages as paclets. Not suited for every type of work but fits my needs.

Comment: This method works well enough when doing ctrl-n to generate a new notebook, but does not seem to work when first opening a mathematica. Is there a way to get this to work in that case, and further to get it to apply to already created notebooks?