# How can I create a template for Mathematica notebook with predefined initialization cell?

Tags: notebooks, templates

I have created an initialization cell with options. I would like to create a template, which already contains these cells, when I open a new notebook.

Is there any opportunity to create such a template file?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: Maybe it can be done by doing something (say `NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], Cell[...]]`) inside `NotebookDynamicExpression` option of `StyleData["Notebook"]`. Do save your work before trying anything evolving `NotebookDynamicExpression`! Wrong code can crash the FrontEnd easily!

Comment: You can add an `InputAlias` that inserts this by using `NotebookRead` to get the `Cell` expression and then you can this alias to either the `Default.nb` stylesheet or make your own. Then when you want this template you just have to type `Esc-template-Esc` or something and it will insert itself.

Comment: related: [Create new notebook at fixed size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100432/5478)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can do this. Indeed, I find it a great way of standardising workflows.

The image below is an example of a notebook that is automagically generated from a palette.

[image]

Everything in the notebook, including the image at the base (a hyperlink to my employer's website), the signature which is a `mailto:` hyperlink and the dynamic dropdown header is generated from the palette. It's displayed at 75% magnification to get it all onscreen, but I generate it at 100%.  The stylesheet employs corporate colors and is custom.

It's essentially combination of `TextCell[]` within `CreateDocument[]`:

```
CreateDocument[{
            TextCell["Title", "Title", CellTags -> {"Title"}], 
            TextCell["Subtitle", "Subtitle", CellTags -> {"Subtitle"}], 
            TextCell["Abstract", "Abstract", CellTags -> {"Abstract"}],
(* more of the same *)}, (* with options ...*)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @dwa: could you please give the code generating the above template, which I like it very much. I would appreciate it much.

Comment: @Tugrul Temel: Try material here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/ah0322rb1l8jrragr6etx/h?dl=0&rlkey=28wpgtzy0r269z2j1hjpg5key