# How can I evaluate a library file (.wl extension) automatically on save?

Tags: import

I would like to have my library functions update on save so they are immediatly available in my notebook file where the library is imported. Effectively like clicking the "Run All Code" button after saving the library (.wl file) so the updated function is immediatly available in the notebook (.nb file). See picture below.

[image: Image of importing a library file]

Comment: Add this to the Notebook with the library functions `SetOptions[InputNotebook[], AutoGeneratedPackage -> Automatic]`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I am not sure this solution is exactly what I am looking for. I edited my question and added some more details.

Comment: I use [notebook specific contexts](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/AutomaticallyUseSeparateContextsForDifferentNotebooks.html) so symbols defined in one notebook are not visible in another notebook even when running on the same kernel. So I use `AutoGeneratedPackage` which creates the `.wl` file when the notebook is saved and then I `Get` the file in the notebook in which I want to use the definitions.

Comment: For your use case you can intercept the File / Save menu command and run code to select all input cells and evaluate them. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66239/58370).